# I getSyntaxError: No number after minus sign in JSON at position 1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, file-upload, replicate

I am tying to work with the replicate model `visoar/product-photo:edf42659dae0da88a26dba4912e7e4bb6c2fba25b1e1c6a5464cf220e467bce0`, but when i provide him with an image and a prompt like that in page.tsx:

```
"use client"

import { LandingNavBar } from '@/components/landing-navbar';
import React, { useState, ChangeEvent, FormEvent } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Card, CardFooter } from '@/components/ui/card';
import { Download } from 'lucide-react';

const ProductPhoto = () => {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState<string>('');
  const [images, setImages] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleFileChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = e.target.files?.[0];
    setSelectedImage(file || null);
  };

  const handlePromptChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setPrompt(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const formData = new FormData();

      if (selectedImage) {
        formData.append('promptimg', selectedImage);
      }
      
      formData.append('prompt', prompt);

      setImages([]);
      const response = await axios.post("/api/image", formData);

      console.log(response.data);
      setImages(response.data);

      // Handle the response as needed
      console.log(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
      // Handle errors here
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <LandingNavBar />
      <div className="mt-[30px]">
        <h1 className="text-6xl text-white  mb-[50px]">Upload your photo</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            name="promptimg"
            className="block text-sm text-white border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-transparent dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400"
            type="file"
            onChange={handleFileChange}
          />
          <input
            name="prompt"
            className="block text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer text-black mt-6"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Background description"
            value={prompt}
            onChange={handlePromptChange}
          />

          <button
            type="submit"
            className="text-white bg-gradient-to-r from-sky-400 via-cyan-600 to-blue-700 hover:bg-gradient-to-br focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-cyan-300 dark:focus:ring-cyan-800 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center mt-6"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 gap-5 mt-8">
            {images.map((src) => (
              <Card key={src} className="rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
                <div className="relative aspect-square">
                  <img alt="image" src={src} width={500} height={500} />
                </div>
                <CardFooter
                  className="p-2 bg-slate-400 h-10"
                  onClick={() => window.open(src)}
                >
                  <Download className="block m-auto w-20 " />
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
            ))}
          </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductPhoto;
```

Here is my api endpoint:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { auth } from '@clerk/nextjs';
import Replicate from "replicate"

const replicate = new Replicate({
    auth: process.env.REPLICATE_API_TOKEN!,
})

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const { userId } = auth();
    const body = await req.json();
    const { prompt } = body;
    const { promptimg } = body; 

    if (!userId) {
      return new NextResponse('Unauthorized', { status: 401 });
    }

    if (!prompt) {
      return new NextResponse('Prompt is required', { status: 400 });
    }

    const response = await replicate.run(
        "visoar/product-photo:edf42659dae0da88a26dba4912e7e4bb6c2fba25b1e1c6a5464cf220e467bce0",
        {
          input: {
            image_path: promptimg, 
            prompt: prompt,
          }
        }
    );

    return NextResponse.json(await response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('[IMAGE ERROR]', error);
    return new NextResponse('Internal error', { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

I am getting this error `SyntaxError: No number after minus sign in JSON at position 1` and I don't really understand it I have worked with replicate and nextjs the same way before and It has never given me this error , can somebody help me?

Comment: What's the response you're trying to treat as JSON? Because apparently it's not JSON, it's something starting with `-` but then not followed by a digit.

Comment: I am trying to get the response object and in the page.tsx get the data and the image link that it returns

Comment: How does that answer my question? Again: What *is* the response? Look in the devtools' Network panel. You'll find that it's not JSON, hence the error.

Comment: In the network panel there is nothing but in the console it logs
Object { stack: "AxiosError@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:24:19\nsettle@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12\nonloadend@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:126:66\n", message: "Request failed with status code 500", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, response: {…} }

Comment: You need to repeat your request with the network panel open, so you can see the response. But that error in the console should give you an idea what's going on even without it.

Answer (score 2):

When you use "form-data" the information is sent as multipart/form-data and not as application/json.

The error you get is because you are trying to parse JSON data in your route.
But the data it received isn't in JSON format.

To fix this:
Parse the content as formdata in your route, like:

```
 const formData = await req.formData();
```

And then you can get specific content like:

```
const selectedImage = formData.get('promptimg');
```